# What is the result type of OrderedDict in Python?

Tags: python, ordereddict

Regarding OrderedDict, what does it exactly returns for its type? For example following code

```
od = OrderedDict()
od['a'] = 1
od['b'] = 2
od['c'] = 3
od['d'] = 4
print(od)
```

Result is:

```
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
```

The result set seems to be pair of tuples in the list, is that right? But in fact I am able to access it the way I access dictionaries, like:

```
print(od['a'])
1
```

What am I getting wrong and how is the result interpreted?

Comment: The str representation of an `OrderedDict` conveys to you the fact that it is ordered. It's an ordered list of key-value tuples

Comment: You are printing a representation of the ordered dict that shows you one way to create the same ordered dict.

Comment: Thank you , but why is it formatted like a tuple ?that is what is confusing me

Comment: @Amir because `od == OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])` -> `True`

Comment: Because the dict constructor can take an iterable of 2-tuples and make it into a dict. You can copy-paste the result and run it to get the same `OrderedDict` recreated. Also, `dict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])` will work just fine

Comment: This can be seen by inspecting the `collections` code. `OrderedDict`'s `__repr__` has `return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, list(self.items()))`. You can try doing `list(d.items())` on any dict and get the same output

Answer (score 2):

The `repr` of `OrderedDict` is showing how you could *construct* an equivalent `OrderedDict`. The `repr` of *any* type, ideally, serves this purpose; assuming no `<>` are involved (to indicate it's not a programmatically useful `repr`), you should be able to copy and paste that back into an interactive interpreter and produce an equivalent object. This sometimes breaks down when the objects inside it don't have useful `repr`s themselves, but for simple built-in literals like this it's correct.

Pre-3.7, there was no language guarantee that plain `dict`s were ordered, so it couldn't use a `dict` as the "argument", and instead chose to use a `list` of `tuple`s as a semi-arbitrary available ordered sequence. But that's just showing what you'd pass to the constructor to recreate it, it's still a `dict`, so no features or `list`s or `tuple`s are involved.

They *could* change the `repr` at this point to use a `dict` literal, but I suspect they do not to ensure code (e.g. doctests) that rely on the old `repr` format doesn't break (it hardly matters what it looks like after all, so long as it's accurately depicting *some* way to recreate it).

Answer (score 0):

The type of an OrderedDict is `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> type(od)
<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>
```

It's a subtype of `dict`, that's why you can use it like a normal dictionary:

```
>>> issubclass(OrderedDict, dict)
True
>>> isinstance(od, dict)
True
```